# How do I check which packages are being installed in next13 build?

Tags: javascript, next.js, build, next.js13

Since next 13 `devDependencies` may not be a reliable way to separate packages.

I would like to know which packages are being installed when I trigger `next build`.

How do I check which packages are being installed?